# Pattern type markers do not work

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am using A-Frame and trying to use some personalized markers.
Following the instructions, I used `[pattern generator][1]` and downloaded a .patt file, and then stored it as pat/xxxx.patt and specified it as:

```
<a-marker type="pattern" patternUrl="pat/xxxx.patt">xxxxxxxx</a-marker>
```

This did not work.

When it is as below, works all fine.

```
<a-marker preset="kanji">xxxxxxxx</a-marker>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

- using url instead of patternUrl:

  `<a-marker type="pattern" url="patterns/patt.patternName">
   <a-entity></a-entity>
  </a-marker>`
- Make sure the url is valid
- Make sure the pattern generator working well.

Comment: thank you so much and I now know the problem. I was using glitch then did not work. However, placed the .patt file in a folder and uploaded to a server and it worked!!!

Comment: You had Your .patt file as an asset ?

Comment: well actually I gave up using glitch for that and tested it on a web server. However, I haven't tried using "url" yet instead of "patternUrl".  Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @KkMm no problem, the option from my anwser works for me, was curious about glitch, for the filepath's in the assets folder are different from the other files.

Comment: Hi Piotr! the "url" option worked on glitch! So thank you so much again for all the help you provided here. ;->